# UILabel background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to change the UILabel background color with this code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    m_ShopName.text = m_CurrShop.m_Name;
    m_ShopAddress.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor; 
}
```

but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    m_ShopName.text = m_CurrShop.m_Name;
    m_ShopAddress.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
UILable *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,50,200)];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I always did the following

m_ShopAddress.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];

When I wanted to change the alpha...

m_ShopAddress.alpha = 0.0f;

Answer (score 0):

An alpha value of 0 means, it's fully *transparent*. That's probably why nothings happens (whatever you mean by that).

And I wouldn't access the background color of the *layer*, but of the *UILabel* directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard, check to see if you have a color for the view background in the storyboard.  The view background color was overriding the layer color for me.  I changed the background color for the view in the storyboard to default and this fixed it for me.

So I had the code:

```
func select() -> Void {
    imageViewBackgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cellImageView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cellLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

The cellLabel was the view background that was not changing.  I had at one time set a background color for the view in the Storyboard.  Once I changed the view background for the cellLabel to default the layer color took effect.

[View Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v8Ig.png)